# Вставка переменой php в JS (в график highcharts)

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Дано:

1. график на **js** - [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/kanzafarov/v260s319/#&togetherjs=AK9pv1zOLT);
2. массив в **php** с кол-вом статей за год помесячно - $montharr;

Как передать значения массива $montharr (**php**) в data графика (**js**)?

```
series: [{
            name: 'Фішки',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [15, 22, 20, 36, 55, 44, 48, 33, 61, 33, 44, 54],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' шт'
            }
```

Comment: `echo "'" . implode(', '  $montharr) . "'";`

Comment: Делай нормально без костылей ajax запросом

Answer (score 1):

Для передачи данных из PHP в JS отлично подходит [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

Простейший пример:

```
<?php
$data = [1,2,3,4];
$jsData = json_encode($data);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?=$jsData?>;
console.log(data);
</script>
```